# add `DEBUG=1` commands to windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, kivy

I'm trying to use [kaki](https://github.com/tito/kaki)
library with kivy and python but to use it you need to run

```sh
DEBUG=1 python main.py
```

but I'm facing this error

```sh
DEBUG=1 : The term 'DEBUG=1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ DEBUG=1 python main.py
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DEBUG=1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

but I can find any source about how to add this command to my path

I'm using

python:3.7
windows 10

I will add any information if need it

Comment: Did you try with `set DEBUG=1` and then launching `python main.py`?

Comment: how I can do that any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can write to an environment variable which will be inherited by child processes, like this:

```
PS ~> $env:DEBUG = 1
PS ~> python main.py
```

Or as two statements on a single line:

```
$env:DEBUG = 1; python main.py
```

Python will now get the value `1` when resolving the `DEBUG` environment variable

In `cmd.exe` you can use the `set` keyword:

```
C:\> set "DEBUG=1" && python main.py
```

Comment: its possible to do this without using PowerShell because it difficult to use

Comment: actually PowerShell is much easier to use because it doesn't have the legacy quirks in cmd. @MathiasR.Jessen that won't work because spaces in cmd are important. You need `set "DEBUG=1" && python main.py`